# Hardware recommendations: what's the limit?

Tags: discussion, scope, shopping-recommendations

A fairly common problem when running an OS other than Windows is finding well-supported hardware. I'm actually surprised we're not getting more questions about this. Well, [we've just had one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12275), and I wonder how we should respond.

Do we want to have a question about touchpads with certain specific requirements? A general question about pointing devices? A general question about finding hardware support lists?

Related prior discussions:

- [Date specific questions](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/date-specific-questions) Doesn't go beyond “product recommendations bad”. I want to distinguish between *recommendations* (what's a good X) and *information* (what X works under Linux).
- [Can we allow somewhat time-sensitive 3D graphics hardware questions?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/538/can-we-allow-somewhat-time-sensitive-3d-graphics-hardware-questions) The responses were specifically about a certain subcategory of questions (general questions about foo devices).
- For [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/): http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1186/are-hardware-recommendations-considered-off-topic It's easier for Ubuntu which has a few [official sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work); and even that is incomplete (there's a good chance none of the hardware on these lists is available in your part of the world).
- For [Super User](https://superuser.com/): [hardware recommendations are shopping questions and those are evil](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=shopping). But [niche cases can be ok, perhaps](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2324/in-defense-of-obscure-niche-hardware-recommendation-questions).

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/69/29)? [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1203/29) was a long time ago.

Comment: @xenoterracide: Thanks for the reference. No, that's not what I'm asking about, see my edit (recommendations ≠ information).

Answer (score 7):

Here's my view on this.

- We should have a general question on “how do I find hardware compatibility information before buying”, with pointers to various compatibility databases. Probably CW with a single answer.
- Some hardware categories deserve more specific questions, for example [graphics cards](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/how-do-i-choose-a-graphics-card-for-linux).
- Hardware recommendation questions that have very specific requirements that aren't easily solved by checking the vendor-listed information or official hardware compatibility lists should be allowed. More general questions should be closed (with a reference to the generic questions).
- Questions asking where to buy are right out.

Comment: so probably two canonical questions as outlined in point #1 and #2 -- I think that should cover the vast majority of it

Comment: Generally agree. I'd add wireless NICs to the list that require more specific questions. It'd be nice to know which chipsets are supported. But this is generally pretty distro specific with varying blacklists and the like. Out of interest to which compatibility list would the CW point? Is there one that's any good?